# Need help on switching the order of integration.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to switch the order of integration for:

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{-x}^{x} y^2 cos(xy)dydx $$

I've drawn it and I understand that it slices the interval [0,1] on x axis, making vertical slices from x=0 to x=1. Also, the inner integral tells me that bottom of each slice is y=--x and top, y=x.

To switch the order, I want to make it a vertical slice which means I'm going from interval [-1,1] on the y-axis(which I'm fairly certain on this), and bottom of the slice is x = -y and top, x = y,  right?

From this, I've obtained

$$ \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-y}^{y} y^2 cos(xy)dxdy $$
but after evaluating the integral on wolfram alpha, I get different answers.

Could someone help me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The original region is all to the right of the $y$ axis, but in your re-write some parts are to the left of the $y$ axis. See my answer, if questions let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse order, as you say $y$ will go $-1$ to $1.$ However since the formula for $x$ changes at $y=0,$ you need the sum of two integrals, one in which $x$ goes from $y$ to $1$ [with $y \in [0,1]$] and the other in which $x$ goes from $-y$ to $1$ [with $y \in [-1,0].$]

Comment: Could you please explain to me (even though it sounds trivial) why the original integral isn't expressed as a sum of two integrals? I don't get how to determine whether the formula changes at a certain point. I understand for the switched integral that for y>0 the area is under y = x and for y<0 the area is under y = -x.

Comment: In the original integral, for a fixed $x$ the vertical line through the region has lowest $y$ value $-x$ and highest $y$ value $x.$ So for that there is no need for two integrals. Note that in the second re-ordered integral, for a given $y$ the rightmost point is always $1$ [sketch region to see] but the formula for the leftmost point depends on whether the given $y$ is positive or negative, hence the need for two integrals.

Answer (score 0):

The substitution $y=xz, dy = x\,dz$ is your friend.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{-x}^{x}y^2\cos(xy)\,dy\,dx \stackrel{SUB}{=} \int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{-1}^{1}x^3 z^2\cos(x^2 z)\,dz\,dx \stackrel{SWAP}{=} \int_{-1}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}x^3 z^2\cos(x^2 z)\,dx\,dz $$
Now you may patiently check that:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^3 z^2 \cos(x^2 z)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\left(z\sin z-1+\cos z\right)$$
so that the original integral equals:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\left(z\sin z-1+\cos z\right)\,dz = \color{red}{2\sin(1)-1-\cos(1)}.$$